# Azure Data Factory LDAP Connection

Tags: oracle, azure, ldap, azure-data-factory

Using a self-hosted integration runtime, I would like to use Azure Data Factory to connect to an on-premise Oracle database. Using the provided Oracle linked service, I can specify Host and Port, which works fine. Now I need to make a connection using an LDAP server, and I cannot find a way to do this using any connector in Azure Data Factory. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Teradata connector` to authenticate LDAP.

Create Teradata linked service in Azure Data Factory.

Browse to the `Manage` tab on the left panel in your Azure Data Factory and select `Linked Services`, then click `+ New`.

[image]

Search for **Teradata** and select the Teradata connector.

[image]

Configure the service details, select `Authentication type` as **LDAP** and test the connection, and create the new linked service.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, this linked service only works for Teradata sources, it seems that I can't use it for an Oracle source.

Comment: it supports LDAP auth also.

Comment: Yes, but when I try to specify the LDAP server name, it says that the Teradata server can't be reached. This makes sense, since I am not using a Teradata server.